# How to change auto generated error class in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working with validation in MVC 3. I know that if the validation is not pass, the incorrect fields are automatically added `input-validation-error` class and they will turn into red thanks to default CSS. But what if I use another theme downloaded from Internet? Maybe its error class is just `error` or something else.

My question is, how can I change the `input-validation-error` class in my code? Is there any way beside using jQuery?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: do you want to change the css for `input-validation-error`?

Comment: Yes, I want to apply another CSS on errors.

Answer (score 0):

These are the default validations that comes with MVC, you can override as well in you view

```
/* Styles for validation helpers
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
.field-validation-error
{
    color: #ff0000;
}

.field-validation-valid
{
    display: none;
}

.input-validation-error
{
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}

.validation-summary-errors
{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff0000;
}

.validation-summary-valid
{
    display: none;
}
```

Instead of overriding you can add another css to the existing validationMessageforclass

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Id, null, new { @class = "className" })
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't want to write CSS. As I've said, I download a theme from Internet, which already has CSS class for error. I want to use them instead of creating my own.

Comment: Then write down that css in <style> tag of your view

Comment: A theme, or template, always has a very very large CSS file. It's hard to locate the `error class`. I always use that class without modifying it. So, I think the best way to apply template to MVC 3 is changing MVC 3 error class.